# Start Countup timer after page load

Tags: php, jquery

I have a game site and used the Count-up timer to track "time taken" by the user to solve the game.

Here each game is loaded into the specific div using jquery load function.

Code:  `$('#gamewindow').load('game.php')`

I have placed the timer in "game.php". In most of the time, the timer is starts running before all game operands and operators are load (especially for the first time when page loads). This need to be avoided.

Timer only need to starts run when the game is ready to play.

I searched for the solution, some solutions are found but which are not work fine for me.

a) sol 1: Start the timer after some time delay. i.e use `setTimeout` function
problem with this sol 1: My problem is not occur all the time. So it consumes the time when it is not necessary.

b) sol 2: Use `$(window).load(function(){ });` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){ });`.

problem with this sol 2: Since i have placed the timer in inner page, the   `$(window).load(function(){ })` not working. If i place the timer script in Main page with `$(window).load(function(){ })`, the timer is working fine for first game but not for the second game since i load the next game using `load` function.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: why not load the game (disabled), the user clicks a "Start" button, game is enabled on click and timer is started

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that script will start when everything is loaded you can use jQuery `ready` function to start loading game (not to start the timer).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // load game
});
```

Comment: For the first time, i loaded the game using jQuery(document).ready(function() { }); function only. And for the next games, i called the javascript function to load game when the current game is completed.

Comment: You can try to start timer from `load` callback (third param) when changing games.

Comment: Thanks. Now i tried the load callback from here:- Ref URL: "http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function" . Now its better with Firefox and Chrome. But not with IE 9.